# Split string after the = sign

Tags: vb.net, split

I can't seem to work out how to get a value from my string using VB.net

If I have a string in my textbox that says:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="MyServer",qop="auth",algorithm="MD5",maxbuf=1000,nonce="3b010c090c0a0000c0a80157c7007f03c5",opaque="4e6573732041636365737320436f6e74"
```

How can I get each of the values after the = in the string.

I have tried using

```
Dim s = "WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm='MyServer',qop='auth',algorithm='MD5',maxbuf=1000,nonce='3b010c090c0a0000c0a80157c7007f03c5',opaque='4e6573732041636365737320436f6e74'"
                        Dim pattern = "="
                        Dim matches = Regex.Matches(s, pattern)
                        Dim values = matches.OfType(Of Match).Select(Function(m) m.Value)

                        For Each v In values
                            MsgBox(v)
                        Next
```

But it only returns the = in the messagebox.

I want to be able to get just the part after the = sign.

Anyone able to help?

I have tried using the following but it still includes the realm= qop= etc.. in the string. (but includes it at the end of the next item.

```
 Dim s = "WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm='Ness Access Control',qop='auth',algorithm='MD5',maxbuf=1000,nonce='3b010c090c0a0000c0a80157c7007f03c5',opaque='4e6573732041636365737320436f6e74'"
                        Dim result_array As Array = Split(s, "=", 6)

                        For Each v In result_array
                            MsgBox(v)
                        Next
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks, I will remember that for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A case for a specific string extension.
How to transform a specific formatted string in a Dictionary with keys and values

```
Public Module StringModuleExtensions
    <Extension()>
    Public Function ToStringDictionary(ByVal str as String, _
                                      ByVal OuterSeparator as Char, _
                                      ByVal  NameValueSeparator as Char) _
                                      As Dictionary(of String, String)
        Dim dicText = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
        if Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) then
            Dim arrStrings() = str.TrimEnd(OuterSeparator).Split(OuterSeparator)
            For Each s in arrStrings
                Dim posSep = s.IndexOf(NameValueSeparator)
                Dim name = s.Substring(0, posSep)
                Dim value = s.Substring(posSep + 1)
                dicText.Add(name, value)
            Next
        End If
        return dicText
    End Function
End Module
```

Call with

```
Dim test = "WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm=""MyServer"",qop=""auth"",algorithm=""MD5"", maxbuf=1000,nonce=""3b010c090c0a0000c0a80157c7007f03c5"",opaque=""4e6573732041636365737320436f6e74"""
Dim dict = test.ToStringDictionary(","c, "="c)
For Each s in dict.Keys
    Console.WriteLine(dict(s))
Next
```

(probably you need to remove the WWW-Authenticate line before.

Comment: I think this is C code you have used. I am doing this in VB.net not C.

Comment: Right, my bad, translated and checked with linqPAD. Seems good.

Comment: Good Job.. Does exactly what I want it to do!

Answer (score 2):

[Regular Expressions!](http://xkcd.com/208/)

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim s As String = "WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm='MyServer',qop='auth',algorithm='MD5',maxbuf=1000,nonce='3b010c090c0a0000c0a80157c7007f03c5',opaque='4e6573732041636365737320436f6e74'"

        'Regular Expression, matches word before equals, and word after equals
        Dim r As New Regex("(\w+)\='([^']+)'")

        'All the matches!
        Dim matches As MatchCollection = r.Matches(s)
        For Each m As Match In matches
            'm.Groups(1) = realm, qop, algorithm...
            'm.Groups(2) = MyServer, auth, MD5...
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups(2))
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

And if you want everything in a nice key-value dictionary:

```
    Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    For Each m As Match In matches
        'm.Groups(1) = realm, qop, algorithm...
        'm.Groups(2) = MyServer, auth, MD5...
        dict(m.Groups(1).ToString()) = dict(m.Groups(2).ToString())
    Next
```

Comment: if its not a silly question, how to do I view the console? I know you are writing to it but where do I find it in VB.net 2012? (I am a little rusty with VB at the min)

Comment: If you're using a Windows application, just replace Console.WriteLine(...) with MessageBox.Show(v)

Comment: Thanks for comfirming that, I had noticed a few sample codes that always show console.write and I couldn't work out where to find the console. Using a messagebox works good for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) function.

```
Dim logArray() As String
logArray = Split(s, "=")
For count = 0 To logArr.Length - 1
    MsgBox(logArray(count))
Next
```

Comment: just looked at that but it's only doing 1/2 of what I want. still includes realm= as part of string that returns.

Comment: I can't run any code so that's about as far as I can get.  This one has a nifty approach for easier access to the key/value pairs.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077340/how-to-convert-a-string-of-key-value-pairs-to-hashtable-or-dictionary-or

Comment: I have just updated my origanl question, which shows you what I have done for the split function in my code.